# create database using mysqli with oops and insert value in database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am getting error at insertion time so I am confused. Please help me or suggest me best tutorial for oop

*testdb.php page*

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define ('DB_USERNAME', 'ashish');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'ashish33'); 
define ('DB_DATABASE', 'users');

 class DB_Class 
    {
function __construct() {
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
}}
```

*testclass.php page*

```
class user {

    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $fullname;   
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;
        $this->lname = $lname;
        $this->fullname = $fullname;
        $db = new DB_Class();
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, fullname) values ('$this->fname', '$this->lname','$this->fullname')") or die(mysqli_error());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

*post.php*

```
$userTest = new user();
$userTest->fname = $_POST['fname'];
$userTest->lname = $_POST['lname'];
$userTest->fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
?>
```

Comment: what error your getting.

Comment: When you create a new user, the values of the object are assigned and saved to db. Afterwards you assign the POST vars. You have to get all of this out of the constructor or assign the variables to the constructor.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, on line $result = mysqli_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside the parameters of the constructor instead:

```
include 'testdb.php';

public function __construct($fname, $lname, $fullname) 
{
    $this->fname = $fname;
    $this->lname = $lname;
    $this->fullname = $fullname;
    $db = new DB_Class();
    $conn = $db->connect();
    // $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, fullname) values ('$this->fname', '$this->lname','$this->fullname')") or die(mysqli_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Then, the initialization:

```
$userTest = new user($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['fullname']);
```

Sidenote: Since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements.

EDIT: You forgot a `return` on the `DB_class`:

```
class DB_Class 
{
    public $conn;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $this->conn = $connection; // return the mysqli instance
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have used this method but getting error on  $result = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(f

Comment: @user3364529 are you sure the `DB_Class` is found in this file?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

Comment: i have print print_r($db) then i have got DB_Class Object ( )

Comment: @user3364529 is `testdb.php` included inside `testclass.php`? `include 'testdb.php'`

Comment: on testdb.php page and i have include this page as require_once(testdb.php); on testclass.php

Comment: @user3364529 oh okay i see, you forgot to return the mysqli instance on `testdb.php`, check my edit

Comment: i am still getting Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in on the insert query line

Comment: @user3364529 okay, check my edit, i changed the whole answer try it again

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_Class::connect()  on this  $db = new DB_Class(); line

Comment: @user3364529 this should be working fine by now, i edited the `DB_class.php`

Comment: please tell me how to fetch data from database friend i am new in oop concept so i am getting problem .thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try the below code in 

class user extends DB_Class{

    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $fullname;   
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); //add this line of code 

    }
    public function insert($fname, $lname, $fullname)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;
        $this->lname = $lname;
        $this->fullname = $fullname;
        $db = new DB_Class();
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, fullname) values ('$this->fname', '$this->lname','$this->fullname')") or die(mysqli_error());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Comment: showing undefined variable  on these lines $this->fname = $fname;